# How can I get a result from mysql_fetch_row (or mysql_fetch_array)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM allowedUsers WHERE UserID = '" . $kUserID . "'";
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery, $db);
if(!result)
{
    echo "Error running query <br>" . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row[2];
}
```

I run the SQLQuery in phpMyAdmin and I am getting a valid result (1 row)
the table (allowedUsers) has 6 fields
I can't get anything out of the DB.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code looks fine. Is there really no output in $row? Are you sure the user ID exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PHP.net's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), you don't need to pass `$db` to `mysql_query()`.  Take a look at the example code:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("mydb");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

It may be helpful to see your connection code, ensure you've selected a database, etc.

Comment: Take a look at @thetaiko's answer, as well.  He has a good point which may show you the actual error you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

`if(!result)` should be `if(!$result)`